# dirty_ratio per device

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, nfs, cache, cifs

I've recently examined a RHEL7.2 that hanged almost totally just because it have written to a CIFS filesystem. With the default settings of `dirty_ratio = 30` and cifs being cached (for both reading and writing), these dirty pages were mostly cifs ones.

Under memory pressure, when system reclaimed most of the read cache, system stubbornly tried to flush&reclaim the dirty (write) cache. So the situation was a huge CPU iowait accompanied with an excellent local disk I/O completion time, a lot of processes in D uninterruptible wait and a totally unresponsive system. OOM killer never engaged, because there *was* free memory that system wasn't giving out. (I think there is also a bug with CIFS, that crawled the flushing to incredibly slow speeds. But nevermind that here.)

I was flabbergasted to find out that kernel treated flushing pages to some slow remote CIFS box in exactly the same way as to super-fast local SSD drive. It's just insensible to have a single `dirty_ratio` bag, it quickly leads to the situation where 30% of RAM contains dirty data from the *slowest* devices. What a waste of money.

The situation is reproducible; setting `dirty_ratio = 1` solves the problem completely. But why do I need to sacrifice the cache of local disks just because I use a cifs mount?

Other than completely disabling caching of some devices, or setting `vm.dirty_ratio` to a very low value, are there any ways to "whitelist" the fast devices to have more write cache? Or to have the slow devices (or remote "devices" like //cifs/paths) use less write cache?

The kernel version for RHEL 7.2 is referred to as 3.10.0-327.  (It is based on 3.10.0, but includes several years worth of backports).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### dirty_ratio per device

> Q: Are there any ways to "whitelist" the fast devices to have more write cache? Or to have the slow devices (or remote "devices" like //cifs/paths) use less write cache?

There are some settings for this, but they are not as effective as you hoped for.  See the `bdi` ("backing device") objects in `sysfs`:

> [linux-4.18/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-bdi](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.18/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-bdi)
>
> **min_ratio** (read-write)
>
> Under normal circumstances each device is given a part of the total
>   write-back cache that relates to its current average writeout speed
>   in relation to the other devices.
>
> The 'min_ratio' parameter allows assigning a minimum percentage of
>   the write-back cache to a particular device.  For example, this is
>   useful for providing a minimum QoS.
>
> **max_ratio** (read-write)
>
> Allows limiting a particular device to use not more than the given
>   percentage of the write-back cache.  This is useful in situations
>   where we want to avoid one device taking all or most of the
>   write-back cache.  For example in case of an NFS mount that is prone
>   to get stuck.

The catch is "this setting only takes effect after
we have more than (dirty_background_ratio+dirty_ratio)/2 dirty data in
total.  Because that is the amount of dirty data when we start to throttle
processes. So if the device you'd like to limit is the only one which is
currently written to, the limiting doesn't have a big effect." Further reading:

- [LKML post by Jan Kara](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20131029203050.GE9568@quack.suse.cz/) (2013).
- The "test case", at the end of this answer.
- [commit 5fce25a9df48](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/5fce25a9df4865bdd5e3dc4853b269dc1677a02a) in v2.6.24. "We allow violation of bdi limits if there is a lot of room on the system. Once we hit half the total limit we start enforcing bdi limits..."  This is part of the same kernel release that added the internal per-device "limits".  So the "limits" have always worked like this, except for pre-releases v2.6.24-rc1 and -rc2.

For simplicity, let us ignore your 30% setting and assume the defaults: dirty_background_ratio=10 and dirty_ratio=20.  In this case, processes are allowed to dirty pages without any delays, until the system as a whole reaches the 15% point.

> Q: The situation is reproducible; setting `dirty_ratio = 1` solves the problem completely.

:-/

This sounds similar to the "pernicious USB-stick stall problem", which LWN.net wrote an article about.  Unfortunately this particular article is [misleading](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480399/why-were-usb-stick-stall-problems-reported-in-2013-why-wasnt-this-problem-so).  It was so confused that it fabricated a different problem from the one that was reported.

One possibility is that you are reproducing a more specific defect.  If you can report it to kernel developers, they might be able to analyze it and find a solution.  Like the interaction with [transparent hugepages](https://lwn.net/Articles/467328/) was [solved](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/1323877293-15401-1-git-send-email-mgorman@suse.de/).  You would be expected to reproduce the problem using the upstream kernel.  Or talk to your paid support contact :).

Otherwise, there is a patch that can be applied to expose the internal `strictlimit` setting.  This lets you change `max_ratio` into a strict limit.  The patch has not been applied to mainline.  If enough people show a need for this, the patch might get applied, or it might encourage some work to remove the need for it.

> My concern is that while potentially useful, the feature
>   might not be *sufficiently* useful to justify its inclusion.  So we'll
>   end up addressing these issues by other means, then we're left
>   maintaining this obsolete legacy feature.
>
> I'm thinking that unless someone can show that this is good and
>   complete and sufficient for a "large enough" set of issues, I'll take a
>   pass on the patch[1].  What do people think?
>
> [1] Actually, I'll stick it in -mm and maintain it, so next time
>   someone reports an issue I can say "hey, try this".
>
> -- [Andrew Morton, 2013](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20131122154505.3e686fcfc584534d555399e5@linux-foundation.org/)

`mm-add-strictlimit-knob-v2.patch` is still sitting in -mm.  A couple of times, people mentioned ideas about better auto-tuning the dirty cache.  I haven't found a lot of work on it though.  An appealing suggestion is to keep 5 seconds worth of write-back cache per device.  However the speed of a device can change suddenly, e.g. depending whether the IO pattern is random or sequential.

### Analysis (but no conclusion)

> Q: I was flabbergasted to find out that kernel treated flushing pages to some slow remote CIFS box in exactly the same way as to super-fast local SSD drive.

These are not treated exactly the same.  See the quote from the BDI doc above.  "Each device is given a part of the total write-back cache that relates to its current average writeout speed."

However, this still makes it possible for the slow device to fill up the overall write-back cache, to somewhere between the 15-20% marks, if the slow device is the only one being written to.

If you start writing to a device which has less than its allowed share of the maximum writeback cache, the "dirty throttling" code should make some allowances.  This would let you use some of the remaining margin, and avoid having to wait for the slow device to make room for you.

The doc suggests min_ratio and max_ratio settings were added in case your device speeds vary unpredictably, including stalling while an NFS server is unavailable.

The problem is if the dirty throttling fails to control the slow device, and it manages to fill up to (or near) the 20% hard limit.

The dirty throttling code that we're interested in was reshaped in v3.2.  For an introduction, see the LWN.net article "[IO-less dirty throttling](https://lwn.net/Articles/456904/)".  Also, following the release, Fengguang Wu presented at LinuxCon Japan.  His [presentation slides](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/images/stories/pdf/lcjp2012_wu.pdf) are very detailed and informative.

The goal was to delegate all writeback for a BDI to a dedicated thread, to allow a much better pattern of IO.  But they also had to change to a less direct throttling system.  At best, this makes the code harder to reason about.  It has been well-tested, but I'm not sure that it covers every possible operating regime.

In fact looking at v4.18, there is [explicit fallback code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/mm/page-writeback.c#L1793) for a more extreme version of your problem: when one BDI is *completely* non-responsive.  It tries to make sure other BDI's can still make forward progress, but... they would be much more limited in how much writeback cache they can use.  Performance would likely be degraded, even if there is only one writer.

> Q: Under memory pressure, when system reclaimed most of the read cache, system stubbornly tried to flush&reclaim the dirty (write) cache. So the situation was a huge CPU iowait accompanied with an excellent local disk I/O completion time, a lot of processes in D uninterruptible wait and a totally unresponsive system. OOM killer never engaged, because there was free memory that system wasn't giving out. (I think there is also a bug with CIFS, that crawled the flushing to incredibly slow speeds. But nevermind that here.)

You mention your system was under memory pressure.  This is one example of a case which could be very challenging.  When "available" memory goes down, it can put pressure on the size of the write-back cache.  "dirty_ratio" is actually a percentage of "available" memory, [which means free memory + page cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480467/writeback-cache-dirty-seems-to-be-limited-to-even-less-than-dirty-background/48099).

This case was noticed during the original work.  There is an attempt to [mitigate](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20110629145554.294330838@intel.com/) it.  It says that "the new dirty limits are not going to avoid throttling the light dirtiers, but could limit their sleep time to 200ms."

### Test case for "max_ratio"

Set up a VM / laptop / whatever, which does *not* have an expensively large amount of RAM.  Run `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M of=~/test`, and watch the write cache with `grep -E '^(Dirty:|Writeback:)' /proc/meminfo`.  You should see dirty+writeback settle around a "set point".

The set point is 17.5%, half-way between 15% and 20%.  My results on Linux v4.18 are [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480467/writeback-cache-dirty-seems-to-be-limited-to-even-less-than-dirty-background/480999#480999).  If you want to see an exact percentage, be aware that the ratios are *not* a percentage of total RAM; I [suggest](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482595/writeback-cache-dirty-seems-to-be-limited-below-the-expected-threshold-where/482729#482729) you use the tracepoint in dirty_balance_pages().

I ran this test with different values of `max_ratio` in the filesystem's BDI.  As expected, it was not possible to limit the write-back cache below the 15% point.

Comment: Great analysis. You've visited a good part of all the nooks and crannies of  the write cache, so it'll be very useful for future readers.

Comment: Great answer! Do you know if it's possible to define default `max_ratio` for any future connected devices? It seems sensible to prevent any given single device to capture all of write cache so I would like to avoid having `max_ratio` at `100` for any given device. Modern desktops may have super fast SSD, HDD, USB memory stick and a slow card reader connected at the same time and granting full buffer to any one of those except the super fast SSD will make the write performance to suck. Having the default at `30` for every device would seem like a pretty good value.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I expect you can write a [udev rule](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/udev) (`SUBSYSTEM=="bdi"` ?) to set the sysfs attribute. Edit: 30 sounds low, I guess it's unusual to be dirtying more than one slow device at a time.

Comment: I would guess it totally depends what you're doing. I'm often hitting a case where my background script is copying all files in the system to backup (HDD) while I'm actively working on the SSD partition and if I then attach an USB memory stick and write stuff on it, I end up with two devices limited by device write performance but my workspace could still use the fast device without any bandwidth issues. However, with `max_ratio` defaulting to `100` the whole write cache is filled and all the applications writing to the fast device fall back to direct write and latency as a result.

Comment: Defaulting to `30` allows having up to 3 devices being bandwidth limited at the same time and still having 10% of the cache for rest of the system without slowdown. In reality, I would actually want to say that  each device has (fictional) `max_background_write_queue_latency` set to e.g. 1 second or 100 ms and *device specific* write cache size would be scaled automatically to achieve that.

Comment: @sourcejedi: I created a new question about the `udev` rule here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/714267/20336

Answer (score 4):

I think you can set the proportion of the dirty ratio per device via

`echo RATIO > /sys/class/bdi/MAJOR:MINOR/max_ratio`

Comment: The `RATIO` above should be a percentage between 0 and 100 of the global max dirty pages cache (/proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes or /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio). See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-bdi for details.

Answer (score 3):

After experimenting, I've found out that `dirty_ratio` "bag" is quite properly balanced. The processes that make pages dirty are somehow constrained. One `cp` process can easily take almost all the write cache possible, but even if you run 10 competing processes bursting, they rarely reach the write cache cap (dirty_ratio) at all.

Therefore, I attribute all the trouble to that CIFS-related bug I've mentioned. If more processes want to write to fast local disk, kernel would have used less for CIFS. Here, more processes wanted to just use memory and kernel couldn't flush&reclaim a large CIFS write cache due to said bug. Probably the 30% dirty_ratio wouldn't be a problem if not the bug.