# Writeback cache (`dirty`) seems to be limited to even less than dirty_background_ratio. What is it being limited by? How is this limit calculated?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cache, sysctl, atop

I have been testing Linux `4.18.16-200.fc28.x86_64`.  My system has 7.7G total RAM, according to `free -h`.

I have default values for the `vm.dirty*` sysctl's.  `dirty_background_ratio` is 10, and `dirty_ratio` is 20.  Based on everything I've read, I expect Linux to begin writeout of dirty cache when it reaches 10% of RAM: 0.77G.  And buffered write() calls should block when dirty cache reaches 20% of RAM: 1.54G.

I ran `dd if=/dev/zero of=~/test bs=1M count=2000` and watched the `dirty` field in `atop`.  While the `dd` command was running, the `dirty` value settled at around 0.5G.  This is significantly less than the dirty background threshold (0.77G)!  How can this be?  What am I missing?

`dirty_expire_centisecs` is 3000, so I don't think that can be the cause.  I even tried lowering `dirty_expire_centisecs` to 100, and `dirty_writeback_centisecs` to 10, to see if that was limiting `dirty`.  This did not change the result.

I initially wrote these observations as part of this investigation: [Why were "USB-stick stall" problems reported in 2013? Why wasn't this problem solved by the existing "No-I/O dirty throttling" code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480399/why-were-usb-stick-stall-problems-reported-in-2013-why-wasnt-this-problem-al/)

---

I understand that half-way between the two thresholds - 15% = 1.155G - write() calls start being throttled (delayed) on a curve.  But no delay is added when underneath this ceiling; the processes generating dirty pages are allowed "free run".

As I understand it, the throttling aims to keep the dirty cache somewhere at or above 15%, and prevent hitting the 20% hard limit.  It does not provide a guarantee for every situation.  But I'm testing a simple case with one `dd` command; I think it should simply ratelimit the write() calls to match the writeout speed achieved by the device.

(There is not a simple guarantee because there are some complex exceptions.  For example, the throttle code limits the delay it will impose to a maximum of 200ms.  But not if the target ratelimit for the process is less than one page per second; in that case it will apply a strict ratelimit.)

- [Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.18/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) -- Linux v4.18
- [No-I/O dirty throttling](https://lwn.net/Articles/456904/) -- 2011 LWN.net.
- > (dirty_background_ratio + dirty_ratio)/2 dirty data in
  >   total ... is an amount of dirty data when we start to throttle
  >   processes -- [Jan Kara, 2013](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20131029203050.GE9568@quack.suse.cz/)
- > Users will notice that the applications will get throttled once crossing
  >   the global (background + dirty)/2=15% threshold, and then balanced around
  >   17.5%. Before patch, the behavior is to just throttle it at 20% dirtyable
  >   memory
  >
  > -- commit 143dfe8611a6, "[writeback: IO-less balance_dirty_pages()](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/mm/page-writeback.c?id=143dfe8611a63030ce0c79419dc362f7838be557)"
- > The memory-management subsystem will, by default, try to limit dirty pages to a maximum of 15% of the memory on the system. There is a "magical function" called balance_dirty_pages() that will, if need be, throttle processes dirtying a lot of pages in order to match the rate at which pages are being dirtied and the rate at which they can be cleaned." -- [Writeback and control groups](https://lwn.net/Articles/648292/), 2015 LWN.net.
- [balance_dirty_pages()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.16/source/mm/page-writeback.c#L1554) in Linux 4.18.16.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.18/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt):

> dirty_ratio
>
> Contains, as **a percentage of total available memory that contains free pages
>   and reclaimable pages**, the number of pages at which a process which is
>   generating disk writes will itself start writing out dirty data.
>
> **The total available memory is not equal to total system memory**.

The available memory is calculated in [global_dirtyable_memory()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.16/source/mm/page-writeback.c#L356).  It is equal to the amount of free memory plus the page cache.  It does not include swappable pages (i.e. anonymous memory allocations, memory which is not backed by a file).

This behaviour applies since [Linux 3.14 (2014)](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/a1c3bfb2f67ef766de03f1f56bdfff9c8595ab14).  Before this change, swappable pages were included in the global_dirtyable_memory() total.

Example statistics while running the `dd` command:

```
$ while true; do grep -E '^(Dirty:|Writeback:|MemFree:|Cached:)' /proc/meminfo | tr '\n' ' '; echo; sleep 1; done
MemFree:         1793676 kB Cached:          1280812 kB Dirty:                 4 kB Writeback:             0 kB
MemFree:         1240728 kB Cached:          1826644 kB Dirty:            386128 kB Writeback:         67608 kB
MemFree:         1079700 kB Cached:          1983696 kB Dirty:            319812 kB Writeback:        143536 kB
MemFree:          937772 kB Cached:          2121424 kB Dirty:            312048 kB Writeback:        112520 kB
MemFree:          755776 kB Cached:          2298276 kB Dirty:            389828 kB Writeback:         68408 kB
...
MemFree:          136376 kB Cached:          2984308 kB Dirty:            485332 kB Writeback:         51300 kB
MemFree:          101340 kB Cached:          3028996 kB Dirty:            450176 kB Writeback:        119348 kB
MemFree:          122304 kB Cached:          3021836 kB Dirty:            552620 kB Writeback:          8484 kB
MemFree:          101016 kB Cached:          3053628 kB Dirty:            501128 kB Writeback:         61028 kB
```

The last line shows about 3,150,000 kB "available" memory, and a total of 562,000 kB data either being written back or waiting for writeback.  That makes it 17.8%.  Although it seemed the proportion fluctuated above and below that level, and was more often closer to 15%.  **EDIT**: although these figures look closer, please do not trust this method.  It is still not the right calculation and it could give very wrong results.  See the followup [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482595/writeback-cache-dirty-seems-to-be-limited-below-the-expected-threshold-where/482729#482729).

---

I found this the hard way:

I noticed there is a [tracepoint in balance_dirty_pages()](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ece13ac31bbe492d940ba0bc4ade2ae1521f46a5#diff-f9a62819096a044efc553c77d4f6fdbb), which can be used for "analyzing the dynamics of the throttling algorithms".  So I used `perf`:

```
$ sudo perf list '*balance_dirty_pages'

List of pre-defined events (to be used in -e):

  writeback:balance_dirty_pages                      [Tracepoint event]
...
$ sudo perf record -e writeback:balance_dirty_pages dd if=/dev/zero of=~/test bs=1M count=2000
$ sudo perf script
```

It showed that `dirty` (measured in 4096-byte pages) was lower than I expected, because `setpoint` was low.  I traced the code; it meant there must be a similarly low value for `freerun` in the tracepoint definition, which is set to `(thresh + bg_thresh) / 2` ... and worked my way back to `global_dirtyable_memory()`.

Comment: Did you ever found a conclusion to this conundrum? The more I read about things like dirty_ratio the more confusing it gets, compounded by the fact that tuning values don't seem to yield much noticeable difference. It seems like there is something deeply rooted inside the kernel that limits all of this, and it seems to me like that aspect of the system was never updated from the older slower disks of the 90's or early 2000's. There's a limbo in this area, on Linux. Because I don't face the same problems or system hangups on Windows (on the same hardware)

Comment: @Winampah Please make your comments *specific* to the post. You haven't explained here what your problem is, and this QA doesn't mention anything like your problem. I think you should be able to message me through the weird chat system (it's not private but it's separate from QA). This QA and the other very similar one is about the exact level global dirty pages will reach. It doesn't say anything about maintaining responsiveness, and definitely nothing about throughput of `swapoff`.

Comment: @Winampah TLDR: I don't want to be snotty about you pinging me; what I'm saying is the next time I come across this post again I'm probably going to flag these comments for removal as irrelevant & cluttering up the QA.