# Why I don't see any increase in "Dirty" memory when writing to a file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, io, cache

I read a bunch of stuff about "Write-back" mechanism today and wanted to try an experiment.

### EDIT: file downloaded from the Internet shows up in `Dirty` stats

Based on the comments, I tried to download a file from the Internet to see if this is "problem" with `dd`.

Indeed, it seems that a file downloaded via `wget` changes `Dirty` stats in `/proc/meminfo`.

`Dirty` size changes  from a few hundreds KBs to 5 MB after the file is downloaded. It stays that way for **at least 10 seconds** (sometimes 20+ seconds) which is still interesting since I'd expect that interval to be less than 5 seconds (based on `vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs`).
`Writeback` (from what I see) stays 0 kB.

Run the watch:

```
Every 1.0s: grep -e Dirty -e Writeback /proc/meminfo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ubuntu-18: Tue Apr 20 13:32:31 2021

Dirty:              5044 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
```

Download the file:

```
root@ubuntu-18:~# wget https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Annual-enterprise-survey/Annual-enterprise-survey-2019-financial-year-provisional/Download-data/annual-enterprise-survey-2019-financial-year-provisional-csv.csv
...
2021-04-20 13:27:11 (2.03 MB/s) - ‘annual-enterprise-survey-2019-financial-year-provisional-csv.csv’ saved [5134576/5134576]
```

### Files generated with `dd` - no impact on `Dirty` stats unless the file is really big

I generated 10MB and 100MB files with `dd` and watched `/proc/meminfo`.
But I haven't noticed any significant increase in `Dirty` memory:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.txt count=100 bs=1M

# watching /proc/meminfo while before, during, and after `dd` is executed
Every 1.0s: grep -e Dirty -e Writeback /proc/meminfo                                                                                                                                                         ubuntu-18: Tue Apr 20 08:06:35 2021

Dirty:               280 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
```

Is there any reason for this behavior?
I thought that, according to these settings (`vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs`), it should take up to 5 seconds before the Dirty memory is written back to the disk:

```
 sysctl -a | grep dirty
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.dirtytime_expire_seconds = 43200
```

Now, when I try to generate a 1GB file then I see an increase in `Dirty` memory size but only while `dd` is running. It drops instantly to a very small value after `dd` completes its job.

I tried with both the smaller and the larger file size multiple times.

I'm running all of this on a Hetzner Cloud VM machine with Ubuntu:

```
root@ubuntu-18:~# uname -a
Linux ubuntu-18 5.4.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 00:01:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@ubuntu-18:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

### Resources

Resources I checked briefly (maybe some of them have an explanation which I have missed or didn't understood):

- https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics
- https://ncona.com/2018/05/linux-page-cache/
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html
- [Writeback cache (`dirty`) seems to be limited to even less than dirty_background_ratio. What is it being limited by? How is this limit calculated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480467/writeback-cache-dirty-seems-to-be-limited-to-even-less-than-dirty-background)
- [Can I watch the progress of a `sync` operation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48235/can-i-watch-the-progress-of-a-sync-operation)
- https://superuser.com/questions/479379/how-long-can-file-system-writes-be-cached-with-ext4

Comment: Try with random. IIRC (but I'm not an expert) zero pages are handled differently (and possibly not allocated, but when modified).

Comment: If you meant for `dd`, then I tried `dd if=/dev/urandom`. Pretty much the same behavior (although the file generation was noticeably slower).

Comment: So I have no idea. Probably `dd` is optimized (just using a limited buffer, and so we have `bs=` part, possibly without memory allocation).

Comment: You might be right about `dd`. I tried to download a CSV file with `wget` and got some interesting stats from meminfo - I'll update the question.